# Load ng-include with the same src again

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a template which has ng-include. I need ng-include to load the same html file which ng-include already loaded.

```
<ng-include src='tabs[0].htmlTemplate'></ng-include>
```

The code above resides in a template file. So, I have a partial view to show results.

result.html is a template which renders the results. Now on successive button clicks, I wish to render the template again.

On button click, the value of tabs[0].htmlTemplate is set.

tabs[0].htmlTemplate is always same as 'temp/result.html'.

Is there any work around?

Comment: add ng-if around the ng-include and trigger ng-if based on when you want to reload

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to answer. Please post your detail code.